# Sonarqube >=5.0 - maven submit causes internal error

Tags: sonarqube

Since upgarding to sonarqube 5 running sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar
aborts due to the following:

```
Error 500 on http://gaia:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=com.acrys.statcoll:statistics&projectName=Acrys%20Statistics%20Analysis%20Web%20Applicatione
```

This is not an issue from uprading as the very same happens with a vanilla plain fresh install.

The current configuration is:
Sonarqube 5.3  (fresh install no plugins)

- OS: NetBSD 6.1_STABLE (GENERIC)  (amd64)
- DB:  Postgresql 9.3.4
- Java: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_u45-internal-
  pkgsrc_1.8.45nb1-b00)
- (problem also exists with: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-internal-pkgsrc_2015_07_30_20_43-b00))

The server side using DEBUG log level ist not logging anything but the following exception:

```
ERROR web[o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://gaia:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=com.acrys.statcoll:statistics&projectName=Acrys%20Statistics%20Analysis%20Web%20Application
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to copy report to file: /usr/pkg/sonarqube/sonarqube-5.3/data/ce/reports/AVMc6tnLiICs49s8iiMm.zip
    at org.sonar.server.computation.queue.report.ReportFiles.save(ReportFiles.java:54) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.queue.report.ReportSubmitter.submit(ReportSubmitter.java:74) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.ws.SubmitAction.handle(SubmitAction.java:86) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:85) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    ...(lengthy stack truncated)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: not opened for reading
    at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream.checkReadable(ChannelStream.java:134) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream.bufferedRead(ChannelStream.java:994) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream.access$300(ChannelStream.java:62) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream$InputStreamAdapter.read(ChannelStream.java:1570) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101) ~[na:1.7.0-internal]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1792) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1744) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(FileUtils.java:1512) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.queue.report.ReportFiles.save(ReportFiles.java:50) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    ... 352 common frames omitted
```

The basic cause being:  java.io.IOException: not opened for reading

Tracing the systemcalls on the server revealed:
The report data is being received and saved to a file in /tmp
The related file descriptor is opend for writing only:

```
2310     65 java     CALL  open(0x7f7fcfa8c3b0,0x601,0x1b6)
2310     65 java     NAMI  "/tmp/RackMultipart20160225-1179439922-1nxhm33"
2310     65 java     RET   open 211/0xd3
```

The second parameter is giving the open flags or-ed from:

```
#define O_WRONLY        0x00000001      /* open for writing only */ 
#define O_CREAT         0x00000200      /* create if nonexistent */
#define O_TRUNC         0x00000400      /* truncate to zero length */
```

The target file mentioned in the server side exception is not being written to. It is being opend and the closed without any write.

The related java code takes the inputStream of the file and just tries to copy the inputStream to the target file.

Deducing from the systemcall trace it seems the inputStream actually is only open for writing only and not for reading.
This would be perfectly consistent with the exception observed.

Is there anything I could change with the configuration oder the runtime to make submission work again?

Or is this a bug introduced with changes for the sonarqube 5 version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some deeper debugging the behaviour observed (causing the question) resulted from a bug with jruby.

Jruby `Tempfile` class mangles open flags by mixing up semantics of `OpenFlags` and `OpenFile` classes. This led to causing the temp file generated for keeping the uploaded data from submit action to be write-only.

So, after having saved the file, the attempt for reading it for copying over to `data` directory for further processing failed,
as the instance was marked to be write-only.

Replacing `jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar` with a fixed version remmedied the problem.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fixed"? I updated the jruby jar to 1.7.23, with no change.

Comment: Nevermind, I discovered that the problem was with nginx rather than Sonarqube. Gotta add `client_max_body_size 1G` to the server or location block.

Comment: @Tzrik: (regarding "fixed" version):  I patched jruby source to using proper flag values, compiled und used that version. I also filed a bug with jruby. ([#3913](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/3913))